# How to get the coordinates of point tapped on an UIImageView so that they are at the same position on all the devices (of different size/resolutions)?

Tags: ios, uiimageview, tags

I have found similar questions before but none were answered satisfactorily. I can get the coordinates of a point where the user taps but my problem arises when the same position has to be recovered if the same image is viewed on different device with different size and resolution. Please refer to the image attached. I have to put the plus icons wherever the user taps on the imageView. Its tagging different parts of an image basically. Now, when I try to put these plus icon on the same image but on a different device using the older device’s coordinates, naturally the exact position is not mapped. Can someone please help me in making this tagging feature generic or dynamic so that the same position can be replicated on every device?[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have make same as you want.Can you please try this one. it will help you.

- When you click on `UIImageView` at that time i have find touch point of the `UIImageView`.You have to need calculate the percentage of `UIImageView` base on `height` and `width`, so it will work on all device.

```
//Your imageView add tapGestureRecognizer event

  imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
  let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapAction))
  self.imageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)

 @objc func tapAction(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

      let touchPoint = sender.location(in: self.imageView)
      print(touchPoint)

      var z1 = touchPoint.x
      var z2 = touchPoint.y
      print("Before Alert Touched point (\(self.z1), \(self.z2)")

      //convert point into Percentage
      let z1per =  z1 * 100 / self.imageView.frame.size.width
      let z2per =  z2 * 100 / self.imageView.frame.size.height

      print("After Alert Touched point (\(self.z1per), \(self.z2per)")


  //whatever you want to add like button or image on tap action.

    let btn = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: touchPoint.x - 15, y: touchPoint.y - 15, width: 30, height: 30))
    btn.layer.cornerRadius = 15
    btn image = UIImage(named: "marker.png") as UIImage?
    btn.setImage(image, for: .normal)
    self.imageView.addSubview(btn)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, let me try this.

Comment: @Ghazalah I have used this code and it is working.So it should be work for you.

Comment: @Ghazalah If it's working for you then can you please help me to get privilege into this community. Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Thanks man, this is the best and closest solution to my problem so far. Have accepted it as the correct answer.

Comment: Great answer very helpful for me thank you so much :)